# SWT Browser embedded in Eclipse plugin doesn't fire popup on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, eclipse, macos, browser, eclipse-plugin

I'm facing the following annoying problem: I created an Eclipse plugin with a dialog having a browser embedded in the form. I have to use org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser for this purpose.

Such browser is intended to display a little page where an iframe and some javascript are used. Moreover, a link is present to open a popup with a window.open() javascript call.

On Windows everything works well, while in Mac OS X the popup doesn't appear. Why?

Thank you very much

EDIT:
This is the actual code that works on Windows but not on Mac:

```
    Browser browser = new Browser(container, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setBounds(10, 100, 300, 200);
    browser.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    browser.addOpenWindowListener(new OpenWindowListener() {
        public void open(WindowEvent event) {
            new Thread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    log.debug("ok is running");
                    //some other stuff here...
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```